# What iOS capability / entitlement is "com.apple.OMC"?

Tags: ios, xcode

`com.apple.OMC`: what is it? Why is it enabled and how do I disable it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple Pay. Found it in this project and it's the only thing enabled on the Capabilites page in Xcode: https://github.com/stripe/stripe-ios/blob/master/Example/Stripe%20iOS%20Example%20%28Simple%29.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj